# Laravel email validation showing wrong message

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I have written in my controller some validation for a sign in form.

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
    'email'     => 'email|required',
    'password'  => 'required'
]);

// If validation fails
if($validator->fails()) {
    // Redirect to some place
    return Redirect::route('account-sign-in-get')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
} else {
    // Attempt to sign in
}
```

In my views i have the following:

```
 @if($errors->has('email'))
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
      {{ $errors->first('email') }}
    </div>
 @endif
```

I enter a string (not a valid email address) and then when i submit, i'm expecting an error that states: "The email must be a valid email address"

Instead i get: "The email field is required"

```
        {{ Form::open(['route' => 'account-sign-in-post', 'role' => 'form']) }}

                <div class="form-group">

                {{ Form::label('email', 'E-mail', ['for' => 'email', 'class' => 'sr-only ']) }}
                {{ Form::text('username', NULL, ['placeholder' => 'Email', 'id' => 'email', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}

                @if($errors->has('email'))
                    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</div>
                @endif

            </div><!-- End of .form-group -->

            <div class="form-group">

                {{ Form::label('password', 'Password', ['for' => 'password', 'class' => 'sr-only']) }}
                {{ Form::password('password', ['placeholder' => 'Password', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'password']) }}

                @if($errors->has('password')) 
                    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</div>
                @endif

            </div><!-- End of .form-group -->

            {{ Form::submit('Sign in', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block']) }}

        {{ Form::close() }}
```

Thank you for reading this. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Post your form? It looks like the email input is not being sent

Comment: I know the blunder i've made. It's the username in the form.. Changed it to email. Works like a charm! Thank you mate :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mistake is in the form.

Particularly where we have an text input that is for the username.

```
 {{ Form::text('username', NULL, ['placeholder' => 'Email', 'id' => 'email', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

It should be for the email:

```
 {{ Form::text('email', NULL, ['placeholder' => 'Email', 'id' => 'email', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

@arkhamDev is right, First you need to add those changes and than follow below stesp.

The order of valiadation rules are important here.
You have below

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
    'email'     => 'email|required',
    'password'  => 'required'
]);
```

Please try below code

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
    'email'     => 'required|email',
    'password'  => 'required'
]);
```